# How can I share resources in KMM

Tags: android, ios, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I want to share resources between android and IOS in kotlin multiplatform but I can't configure the MOKO-RESOURCES library, I get Gradle errors, how can I share resources without MOKO-LIBRARY?

all of the libraries and plugins added in the project build.gradle and shared module build.gradle

I don't know why I can't use  **androidMainApi** because that I commented it

Note: My main package name is **com.sn.testmokokmm**

**Shared module build.gradle.kts**

```
plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform")
    id("com.android.library")
    id("dev.icerock.mobile.multiplatform-resources")
}

kotlin {
    android()
    
    listOf(
        iosX64(),
        iosArm64(),
        iosSimulatorArm64()
    ).forEach {
        it.binaries.framework {
            baseName = "shared"
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        val commonMain by getting
        val commonTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("test"))
            }
        }
        val androidMain by getting
        val androidTest by getting
        val iosX64Main by getting
        val iosArm64Main by getting
        val iosSimulatorArm64Main by getting
        val iosMain by creating {
            dependsOn(commonMain)
            iosX64Main.dependsOn(this)
            iosArm64Main.dependsOn(this)
            iosSimulatorArm64Main.dependsOn(this)
        }
        val iosX64Test by getting
        val iosArm64Test by getting
        val iosSimulatorArm64Test by getting
        val iosTest by creating {
            dependsOn(commonTest)
            iosX64Test.dependsOn(this)
            iosArm64Test.dependsOn(this)
            iosSimulatorArm64Test.dependsOn(this)
        }
    }
}

android {
    namespace = "com.sn.testmokokmm"
    compileSdk = 32
    defaultConfig {
        minSdk = 21
        targetSdk = 32
    }
}
dependencies {
    commonMainApi("dev.icerock.moko:resources:0.20.1")
//    androidMainApi("dev.icerock.moko:resources-compose:0.20.1")
}
multiplatformResources {
    multiplatformResourcesPackage = "com.sn.shared" // required
}
```

**project build.gradle.kts**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath("dev.icerock.moko:resources-generator:0.20.1")
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share 1) your build/gradle setup and 2) the error you are getting?

Comment: @RóbertNagy I didn't get error in compile time but the new resource module is not created

Answer (score -1):

Go to the terminal of android studio (on the bottom of your screen, middle) and run command  ./gradlew generateMRcommonMain